# Posting image to Facebook

Tags: c#, facebook

I am completely new to the Facebook API and am not seeing a whole lot of resources on it for C#. I'm simply interested in posting an image to Facebook. Does anyone have any insight or experience with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at: http://csharpsdk.org
that is the most "official" c# facebook sdk.

What are you writing?  ASP.net/phone/win app?

Start with getting the user authenticated (different depending on what platform) and then take a look at facebook developer documentation for an overview of whats involved in making a post and this: http://csharpsdk.org/docs/making-synchronous-requests for some documentation on making the proper http request using the sdk.

I've not used this but looks like the documentation is coming soon even though its pretty skimpy at the moment.

Goodluck!

Comment: Thanks. Really it's just to interface with another API, but I'm going to end up using WinForms to provide the login stuff and then use like a `FileSystemWatcher` to activate the upload.